# ProgrammingError at column "" does not exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-users, django-postgresql

I added a custom extension to djangos User model and now I'm getting this error on my localhost url:

```
     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column users_account.birthday does not exist
LINE 1: ... "users_account"."id", "users_account"."user_id", "users_acc...
                                                             ^
```

Furthermore, when I tried to migrate my changes I got this error in the terminal:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, chaburah, contenttypes, sessions, taggit, users
Running migrations:
  Applying users.0002_alter_account_birthday...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "birthday" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._account" ALTER COLUMN "birthday" TYPE date USING "birthday"...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/my_chaburah/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/my_chaburah/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 98, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 290, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 131, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 163, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 248, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 131, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 235, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 747, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 231, in _alter_field
    super()._alter_field(
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 963, in _alter_field
    self.execute(
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 192, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/almoni/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_chaburah-AiCSV-sC/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "birthday" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._account" ALTER COLUMN "birthday" TYPE date USING "birthday"...
```

It only appears when I try to either edit an existing User or create a new one.

models.py:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthday = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

admin.py:

```
class AccountInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Account
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Accounts'

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (AccountInline,)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

My original guess was the error was due to the fact that my existing Users have no birthday but that doesn't explain why I can't create a new User. Which makes me think I am unaware of what the actual problem is.

I'm newish to django/SQl so I don't really understand the error itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
# and/or
python manage.py migrate
```

If error still occurs - delete the database, create new and then run above commands. If got still same error - delete the database and all migration files and then run the commands.

PS You probably want `DateField` not `DateTimeField` for birthday storage :)

Comment: I get the error when I run manage.py migrate

Comment: @Eddy Is this the same error? Have you manipulated migration files? Have you run makemigrations? It should not happen otherwise.

Comment: I have manipulated migration files, as in deleted and re-migrated, but I'll edit my post to include exact errors.

Comment: Don't manipulate migration files before you understand how they work: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/ Answer addition: If error still occurs - delete the database, create new and then run above commands. If got still same error - delete the database and all migration files and then run the commands.